okio: can't sync file with JS in kotlin multiplatform
I have following code in KMP:
   val fileSystem: FileSystem = NodeJsFileSystem
   val path = "photo".toPath()
   fileSystem.sink(path).close()

In browser I see in logs smth like:

Exception handled = IOException: openSync is not a function
at toIOException (webpack-internal:///./kotlin/okio-parent-okio-nodefilesystem.js:279:122)
at openFd (webpack-internal:///./kotlin/okio-parent-okio-nodefilesystem.js:272:15)
at protoOf.sink_3ey1xj_k$ (webpack-internal:///./kotlin/okio-parent-okio-nodefilesystem.js:384:14)
at protoOf.sink$default_shv2w8_k$ (webpack-internal:///./kotlin/okio-parent-okio.js:9802:35)
at protoOf.createTempFile_oo2seq_k$ (webpack-internal:///./kotlin/ReverseAcquiring-shared.js:104302:85)
at protoOf.toPhotoInfo_eusk8b_k$ (webpack-internal:///./kotlin/ReverseAcquiring-shared.js:29378:45)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./kotlin/ReverseAcquiring-shared.js:35240:37)
at protoOf.convert_n55856_k$ (webpack-internal:///./kotlin/ReverseAcquiring-shared.js:34406:31)
at protoOf.doResume_5yljmg_k$ (webpack-internal:///./kotlin/ReverseAcquiring-shared.js:35904:29)
at protoOf.resumeWith_b9cu3x_k$ (webpack-internal:///./kotlin/kotlin-kotlin-stdlib.js:8144:34)

Any ideas how to overcome situation?
